# Why is Oracle's TZ_OFFSET wrong for all cities on only one server?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, timezone, utc-time

Why does Oracle think that the timezone offset of Denver is UTC-7:00?
The server time and systimestamp look right.

**Server 1: Oracle 11.2.0.4.0**

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;
    America/Denver

cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
    ZONE="America/Denver"

SELECT * FROM v$timezone_file;
    timezlrg_14.dat 14

SELECT systimestamp FROM dual;
    29-JUN-21 01.29.21.546036000 PM -06:00

SELECT tzabbrev, SUBSTR(tz_offset(tzname), 1, 6), tzname FROM v$timezone_names tz WHERE tzname = 'America/Denver';
LMT -06:00  America/Denver
MST -06:00  America/Denver
MDT -06:00  America/Denver
MWT -06:00  America/Denver
MPT -06:00  America/Denver
```

**Server 2: Oracle 11.1.0.6.0**

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;
    America/Denver

cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
ZONE="America/Denver"
UTC=false
ARC=false

SELECT * FROM v$timezone_file;
    timezlrg.dat    4

SELECT tzabbrev, SUBSTR(tz_offset(tzname), 1, 6), tzname FROM v$timezone_names tz WHERE tzname = 'America/Denver';
LMT -07:00  America/Denver
MST -07:00  America/Denver
MWT -07:00  America/Denver
MDT -07:00  America/Denver
```

Comment: What is `systimestamp on` server 2? Result of `TZ_OFFSET` depends on Daylight-Saving-Time status at the moment when you execute the function.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit systimestamp is the same on server 2. Here's a recent run on both servers, a few seconds apart:
Server 1: `01-JUL-21 03.19.31.175264000 PM -06:00`
Server 2: `01-JUL-21 03.19.37.524027000 PM -06:00`

Comment: What is the result of `TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:SS tzr-tzd-tzh:tzm')`? Perhaps the old time zone file (version 4 vs. version 14) does not define DST for America/Denver, however I did not find anything in the IANA time zone database releases notes.

Answer (score 2):

In the IANA time zone database I found this comment:

```
# From Arthur David Olson (2005-08-22):
# Paul has been careful to use the "US" rules only in those locations
# that are part of the United States; this reflects the real scope of
# U.S. government action.  So even though the "US" rules have changed
# in the latest release, other countries won't be affected.

# Rule  NAME    FROM    TO  TYPE    IN  ON  AT  SAVE    LETTER/S
Rule    US  1918    1919    -   Mar lastSun 2:00    1:00    D
Rule    US  1918    1919    -   Oct lastSun 2:00    0   S
Rule    US  1942    only    -   Feb 9   2:00    1:00    W # War
Rule    US  1945    only    -   Aug 14  23:00u  1:00    P # Peace
Rule    US  1945    only    -   Sep lastSun 2:00    0   S
Rule    US  1967    2006    -   Oct lastSun 2:00    0   S
Rule    US  1967    1973    -   Apr lastSun 2:00    1:00    D
Rule    US  1974    only    -   Jan 6   2:00    1:00    D
Rule    US  1975    only    -   Feb 23  2:00    1:00    D
Rule    US  1976    1986    -   Apr lastSun 2:00    1:00    D
Rule    US  1987    2006    -   Apr Sun>=1  2:00    1:00    D
Rule    US  2007    max     -   Mar Sun>=8  2:00    1:00    D
Rule    US  2007    max     -   Nov Sun>=1  2:00    0   S
```

Looks like the DST rules changed in 2006/2007. I assume file timezlrg.dat version 4 refers still to the old rule.